# Confusing instance of

Tags: java

Not sure why when I make an instance as in 2 the complier fails and 3 succes

```
//Instantiate Class Used To Fill In New Stock Details
CreateStockCodeDetails CreateStockDetailsInput = new CreateStockCodeDetails();
CreateStockDetailsInput.CreateStockCodeDetails(CreateNewStockCode); // (2)
CreateStockDetailsInput.CreateStockDetails(CreateNewStockCode);  // (3)
```

When I name the constructor the same name as the class, it fails. Why?

```
class CreateStockCodeDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public void CreateStockDetails(String StockCode) {
        // This works   
    }
}
```

---

```
class CreateStockCodeDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public void CreateStockCodeDetails(String StockCode) {
        // This fails. Why?
    }
}
```

Comment: use ` punctuation to put your code in it. we can't read it right now.

Comment: In his case he would use four spaces in front of each code line, not the backticks (`).  Blocks of code use four spaces, variable names like `foo` use backticks.

Comment: Those are not constructors. Those are methods. The code as far looks fine (expect from C# style which is confusing to Java developers; variable and method names should start with lowercase). Are you posting the *actual* code?

Comment: I would recommend reading some article about constructors as you are clearly confusing them with methods so you can't even phrase your question correctly. It is also worth reading Java naming convention before you actually start coding something as it will make your code more clear. You don't start a variable name with a capital letter and you don't name your class "CreateSomething", but SomethingCreator or just Something instead depending on what it is actually for.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot put a return type next to a constructor. In your second class declaration the constructor would just be:

```
public CreateStockCodeDetails(String StockCode)
{

}
```

Now you can create the object by doing this...

```
CreateStockCodeDetails var = new CreateStockCodeDetails("WTF is a stock code");
```

The return type is supposed to be implicit on constructors since you always know what type you are constructing....

Your first class declaration works because the method you've declared is not a constructor(since it both has a return type and is NOT the same name as the class), so it is treated as such with a return type of void.

Comment: A constructor can't have a return type because ... what would it return? You call a constructor with "new", and there's no place to accept a returned value.

Comment: He's calling them as methods.

Comment: What was explained by BalusC? As far as I know, his(Stephen's) class declarations are still wrong for the very reason I explained.... Care to elaborate on how it is correct to put a void return type in front of a constructor declaration??

Comment: he is not declaring constructors at all. He is declaring methods. He's just wrongly naming them with uppercase.

Comment: I think he refers to the methods incorrectly. Look at his first 3 lines of code. He is invoking only the default constructor, and then is invoking _methods_. I already voted to close the question, because it is really unclear and bad.

Comment: I really don't get you. The question is badly defined. BalusC aksed very good question that is still unanswered. I don't have an answer to the question because there is no question. For the last hour I have asked for necessary clarifications on at least 5 questions, because OPs didn't feel the need to provide actual errors. As for me providing help - check my answers history ;) Don't get so upset by one downvote. Oh, and where did you see me being hateful?

Comment: I just think its hateful to have such rigid standards for content and go about enforcing them on a website you dont even own (although I understand it is collaboratively administrated). I just dont see the point to deleting and I think it would be a better site if people didnt have to be terrified of the formatting/deleting nazis. If someone can post something and get a solution (even if you dont understand the wording or concept behind the problem or solution) then this site has done its job and people should not interfere with that. Dont like the wording? Look someplace else.

Comment: @Stephen - it's not about not knowing something. That's perfectly fine, and Stackoverflow is a place to ask. The problem is not knowing how to ask. For example "compiler fails" tells us nothing about the problem.

Comment: Hate egos we all have to learn. I'm a pure mathematician not a programmer so what do you expect after 2 days. When people ask me to help them understand something I don't shoot them down - I try and help. Will not be using this website again, it's a pity because most of the people are really nice and very helpful - be cool Bozho

Comment: Haha, as though to illustrate my point... Stephen's comment is exactly why I used the phrase "hateful" while I dont mean any offense by it, there is no other word that comes to mind to describe the behaviour of shooting someone down.

Comment: I did not shoot anyone down.  I just insisted on getting sufficient information in order to solve the problem. Now @Stephen is engaging in needless discussions, rather than providing that information. If he does, I'll be the first to provide an answer.